# Preferred way of getting Future of head from Future[ List[ A ] ]

Tags: scala, future

So... lets say I have a `Future[ List[ A ] ]` and what I want get is a `Future` containing the `first element` of the `list` that is contained by the `Future`.

Considering this is a part of the db access layer what can be the preferred way of doing this ?

```
def getFirstByName( name: String ): Future[ A ] = {
  val aListFuture = ...
  // somehow got the future of list of all A's for this name 
  // Now how do I return a Future[ A ] contaning the head of said list
}
```

The focus of this question is more on `Considering this is a part of the db access layer what can be the preferred way of doing this ?`.

we can do something like following `val aFuture = aListFuture.map(l => l.head)` but what if the list was empty ?

In this question what I am really looking for is "how to design a predictable solution?".

Is there any other choice than to gracefully fail with a domain specific exception ? If not than how do I implement such failure ?

I am currently using the following dirty trick for this,

```
def getFirstByName( name: String ): Future[ A ] = {
  // somehow got the future of list of all A's for this name
  val aListFuture = ...
  aListFuture map( _.head ) match {
    case Some( t: Try[ A ] ) => t match {
      case Success( a: A ) => Promise.successful( a ).future
      case Failure( e: NoSuchElementException ) => Promise.failed( DbNotFound ).future
      case Failure( e ) => Promise.failed( e ).future
    }
    case _ => Promise.failed( new Exception( "Some unexplained exception" ) ).future
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not changing function return type?

Comment: @FatihDonmez Well... that defeats the whole point of the question itself. And I need to do it this way.

Comment: Consider also what to do if the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
val futureOfHead = aListFuture.map (_.head)
```

For case when future returns empty list you may provide default value:

```
val DefaultValue = ...
val futureOfHead = aListFuture.map (_.headOption.getOrElse(DefaultValue))
```

Another option:

```
val futureOfHead = aListFuture.map (_.headOption.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("db layer exception"))
```

Comment: Well true... but isn't this very unpredictable. What if the list was empty ? l.head on an empty list l can not be said very wise, right ? How will you recover from that ?

Comment: Right, but it is up to you how to deal with such case. One option is to provide default value.

Comment: Well... the question is more about `Considering this is a part of the db access layer what can be the preferred way of doing this ?` and less about how to get an unpredictable future.

Comment: And what do you suggest the `defaultValue` can be in case where this is part of the DB layer ?

Comment: It would be better to leave it as headOption.

Comment: It's a db api so It's quite valid to have None for some queries. Trying to cover it in this dao method unnecessary. Consumer of this api should handle it.

Comment: @FatihDonmez Not necessarily... also It is supposed to be consumed by already existing code and thus I need it to be a Future[ A ] .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and then `head`.

```
def map[S](f: (T) ⇒ S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

> Creates a new future by applying a function to the successful result of this future. If this future is completed with an exception then the new future will also contain this exception.

```
val aListFuture = futureList.map(l => l.head)
```

Caller of this dao can handle `Success` and `Failure`

```
future.onComplete( {
  case Success(result) => ..
  case Failure(err) => .. //if head is empty you'll get java.util.NoSuchElementException
}
```

Comment: Well true... but isn't this very unpredictable. What if the list was empty ? `l.head` on an empty list `l` can not be said very wise, right ? How will you recover from that ?

Comment: What if supposed caller already has a contract which requires a `Future[ A ]` ?

Comment: Then you should go with headOption.getOrElse and decide about your default case in the context of application.

Comment: Well... thanks for your input but here I am really looking for a Scala design pattern for such use-cases. Though I am not a high level expert in Scala but I know Scala pretty deep, I can solve this problems in at least 10 ways other than using `Option`... I am just looking for a recommended and elegant solution.

Comment: We all are trying to understand and help. At least three answer depends on same pattern so maybe it would be better to share each 10 other ways you thought at first place with reasons which cause you to think that they're not robust, valid and etc. In this way I believe you can find better answers and broaden knowledge for all of us.

Comment: We can use Either to implement a simple Railway design or use scalaz constructs for more concise design pattern... but both of these will defeat the purpose of coming up a simpler solution which is `Just return the future which will fail with domain aware exception ( let say DbItemNotFound ) in case of where the item is not found.

Comment: I have added a very simple and crude way of achieving the same. But it really is very wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

All anwsers are true but there may be a less error prone solution like this if fits to your problem:

```
val aListFuture = futureList.map(l => l.headOption)
```

which returns a Future[Option[A]] than can be checked by pattern matching.

Also, if you want and have a default value for this you can use:

```
val aListFuture = futureList.map(l => l.headOption.getOrElse(""))
```

Comment: Not sure what's not "robust" about this approach, it is the correct, typesafe approach to representing the value at the head of a list.